# How to call async Task<bool> method?

Tags: c#, winforms, parse-platform

This is the async function i have created, here am getting error while claaing this function on buttion click.

```
public async Task<bool> Login(string UserName, string Password)
    {
        try
        {
            ParseUser User = await ParseUser.LogInAsync(UserName, Password);
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(User.ObjectId);
            var currentUser = ParseUser.CurrentUser;
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }           
    }
```

its getting error while calling.

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Login(txtUserName.Text,txtPassword.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Login Success");                       
        }            
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to asynchronously wait for the `Login` method like this:

```
private async void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (await Login(txtUserName.Text,txtPassword.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Login Success");                       
    }            
}
```

Now, this event handler is asynchronous (by using the `async` keyword) and it asynchronously waits for the `Login` method (by using the `await` keyword).

Please note that in general, it is not recommended to have `async void` methods. However, one exception for this rule are event handlers. So this code is fine.

Answer (score 4):

You need to asynchronously wait for the method as shown below:

```
 private async void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
 var task = Login(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text)
 var result = await task;
 if (result) {
  MessageBox.Show("Login Success");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call async method from sync method:

```
var task = Task.Run(() => Login(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text)).Result;
```